# How to use Plug.Crypto.decrypt?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to encrypt a string and the decrypt it, for encryption i did

```
enc_str = Plug.Crypto.encrypt("my_secret",  "raw_string", {})
```

And for decrypt y tried this two

```
Plug.Crypto.decrypt("my_secret", enc_str)
Plug.Crypto.decrypt("my_secret", enc_str, {})
```

which returns the following errors

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Plug.Crypto.decrypt/2
```

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Plug.Crypto.decrypt/5
```

How can enc_str be decrypted properly?
I Only found 2 references to this methods, but i really dont understand them
https://hexdocs.pm/plug_crypto/Plug.Crypto.html#decrypt/4
https://shyr.io/blog/elixir-encrypt-data-plug-crypto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to [`encrypt/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug_crypto/Plug.Crypto.html#encrypt/4) are:

1. The secret key base, usually taken from `conn.secret_key_base` (which if you are using Phoenix, is set based on your config)
2. Your secret, which acts as salt to encrypt the data
3. The data you want to encrypt - can be any term - no need to be `"raw_string"`
4. Opts specified in the documentation

Example, from inside a plug:

```elixir
encrypted =
  Plug.Crypto.encrypt(conn.secret_key_base, "mmm salty", %{hello: "world!"})
  |> IO.inspect(label: "encrypted")

decrypted =
  Plug.Crypto.decrypt(conn.secret_key_base, "mmm salty", encrypted)
  |> IO.inspect(label: "decrypted")
```

Output:

```elixir
encrypted: "QTEyOEdDTQ.R83_rKqB0vyw2KJmGZmjhEuRqc-En71p--VGDaRhpzOEXHIxeg_TOE4YCvQ.bsuQLhrrKzE0LOFo.qooCxTQrJQ7S8lTRhngprcEgAODvw_IsIgGofAEC1_F3NyIcaocQVns.KqKtO6hVMPk0dxOXjX-67A"
decrypted: {:ok, %{hello: "world!"}}
```

---

Or since you are using Phoenix, you can use [`Phoenix.Token.encrypt/4`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Token.html#encrypt/4) with a conn:

```elixir
Phoenix.Token.encrypt(conn, "mmm salty", %{hello: "world!"})
```

Or an endpoint:

```elixir
Phoenix.Token.encrypt(YourAppWeb.Endpoint, "mmm salty", %{hello: "world!"})
```